# How can I detect changes to properties in a specific entity in Entity Framework Core 2.x?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When a user saves changes to an object `myObject`, I'd like to log the fields that were updated to that object.

I can get an object with

```
var myObject = await context.MyObjects.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

And I see that I can get an `IEnumerable<PropertyEntry>` with

```
var changes = context.Entry(myObject).Properties.Where(x => x.IsModified);
```

But in my `changes` list I don't see the field name anywhere. Also, it seems to take 2 full seconds to make this members query in LINQPad. That doesn't seem right.

How do I complete the following statement?

```
Consolse.Write($"The field {what goes here?} was updated from {change.OriginalValue} to {change.CurrentCalue}.");
```

Other StackOverflow questions I've found are for previous versions of Entity Framework, or override `SaveChanges` and don't look for specific entities.

Update! Got it.

```
public string GetChangeLog<T>(
    ApplicationDbContext context,
    T entity)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var changes = context.Entry(entity).Properties.Where(x => x.IsModified);

    foreach (var change in changes)
    {
        var propertyBase = (IPropertyBase)change.Metadata;
        sb.Append($"\"{propertyBase.Name}\" was changed from \"{change.OriginalValue}\" to \"{change.CurrentValue}\"\n");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.Metadata` property to retrieve a `IPropertyBase`. That will tell you what has actually changed.

Comment: This helps! It's almost working. Can you please check my update?

Comment: @Chris that is a separate question. but a hint - use the change tracker.

Comment: Found OriginalValue in .Properties instead of .Members